# Rendering HTML in AG Grid Column Header (Community v20.0.0 +)

Tags: javascript, angular5, ag-grid

I previously upgraded my AG Grid package from an 18x to 20.0.0 (Community Version).  In the previous version, I was simply able to pass an HTML string to the *colDefs.headerName* property and it would render HTML in the header.

This new version renders header and cell data as a string by default.  So now the column headers are rendering like this:

```html
<span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" role="columnheader">
   "<span id="header-span-1" style="visibility: visible; position: static; display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 5px;">Some Text</span>"
</span>
```

I obviously want to go with the easiest solution, which seems to be using a Cell Renderer (or something similar as described on https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/) that simply returns the HTML.  How could the following be achieved in using the headerName property?

```html
colDef.cellRenderer = function(params) {
    var html = '<span id="header-span-1" style="visibility: visible; position: static; display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 5px;">Some Text</span>';
    return html;
}
```

If it can't, would someone please provide a working example of how to use a header component for what I'm specifically after?   I saw where I could define a template, but it seems like overkill considering I only need what I've described above.  I've searched around and can't seem to find an example.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Dominic's response below, I was able to come up with a solution that didn't require excessive (and unnecessary) effort.  Again, for my particular use case, I have limited control over the column data coming back from the server, but needed to have a way to format it - beyond the functionality provided by AG Grid's *formatter* and *getter* properties.

In my project, the column definitions are provided via a class...

```html
export class colDefs {
    constructor(
        public headerName: any,
        public field: any,
        ...
    ) { } 
}
```

...and instantiated in the applicable typescript components like this:

```html
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  ... // Do stuff
  this.columnDefs[i] = new colDefs(headerName, field, ...);
  ... // Do stuff
 }
```

Taking Dominic's advice, I simply created a new class named *HTMLRenderer* (extended from *HeaderComp*).  I also added a new property to exported class *colDefs* named "headerComponent", and I pass the HTMLRenderer as its value.

```html
import { HeaderComp } from 'ag-grid-community/dist/lib/headerRendering/header/headerComp';
class HTMLRenderer extends HeaderComp {
    init(params) { 
    super.init(params);
    // @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error
    this.eGui.querySelector('[ref="eText"]').innerHTML = params.displayName; 
  }
}

export class colDefs {
    constructor(
        public headerName: any,
        public headerComponent: any = HTMLRenderer,
        public field: any,
        ...
    ) { } 
}
```

Please take note of the *// @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error* comment.  It's needed.  Otherwise, if you're using typescript, it will throw an error and fail to compile.

Finally, in my typescript components that instantiate the *colDefs* class, I pass the applicable values.  But for the headerComponent property, you MUST pass undefined, which basically says that we want to go with the default value as defined in the exported class:

```html
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  ... // Do stuff
  this.columnDefs[i] = new colDefs(headerName, undefined, field, ...);
  ... // Do stuff
 }
```

This did it for me without the overkill that would have been involved with creating a full header component for just a small string of HTML in the header.  The HTML in my AG Grid column headers are rendering now!

Please note there is actually another approach for accomplishing this that involves isolating the HTMLRenderer in its own class file.  You ultimately have to register it as a provider in *app.module* AND in each typescript file you want to use it in...NOT to mention you also have to export the class AND make it an Injectable.

To me, this approach seems like too much work for the little bit of HTML I have in the column headers.

Comment: You need to write a header renderer. However, if your HTML string is simple and mostly concerned with formatting, you could write a simpler solution based on CSS classes and the headerClass field of the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly they decided that HTML wouldn't be useful in the header or accidentally broke it so you can't even use something like ° or Δ for units. Even worse is that the architecture around the header renderer is awful - in order to customize it they want you to also take over handling for sorting, filtering, menu etc. Bizarre that this would be their first assumption but anyway... At least they should provide an `innerRenderer` like they do with cells.

The only thing they export is `headerRootComp` which seems totally useless. In order to not take over all the responsibility for the sorting etc mentioned you have to get the component that they use to render the default header. Note that this isn't officially exported and could change:

```
import { HeaderComp } from 'ag-grid-community/dist/lib/headerRendering/header/headerComp';

class HeaderHTMLRenderer extends HeaderComp {
  init(params) {
    super.init(params);
    this.eGui.querySelector('[ref="eText"]').innerHTML = params.displayName;
  }
}
```

Pass this in as your default renderer:

```
defaultColDef={{
  headerComponent: HeaderHTMLRenderer,
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Dominic.  The line that begins with "this.eGui" is throwing an error:  [ts] Property 'eGui' is private and only accessible within class 'Component'.

Comment: There isn't an issue with the code itself but Typescript, I'm not familiar with TS but I do find it frustrating when it prevents me from doing things I know are fine so I gave up on it. Try adding a `@ts-ignore` comment for it

Comment: Thank you, Dominic!  You helped me solve the problem.  I've updated my original question with the steps I took to solve it, and tried to provide as much feedback as possible, in hopes that it will help someone else.

Comment: Many thanks for this since I was also stuck with the same problem and I have got it working now but I have still got an issue...I have a snapshot test associated with the ag-grid table and that is faling now... I get the following error                                                 

Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
        at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
for this line

import { HeaderComp } from 'ag-grid-community/dist/lib/headerRendering/header/headerComp';

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create a rendering component, really the simplest approach is to apply a css class:

```
gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: 'MyCol',
        headerClass: 'col-css-class',
        ...
    };
```

If you need something more complex, you won't be able to do it without a rendering component.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality was changed in AG Grid 27, now you MUST use a rendering component to display HTML. (Unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to extend default **HeaderComp**, here is a solution in plain JavaScript (ES6) which does not require **Babel**

```
class CustomHeaderComp extends (new agGrid.UserComponentRegistry()).agGridDefaults['agColumnHeader'] {
    init(params) {
        super.init(params)
        this.eGui.querySelector('[ref="eText"]').innerHTML = params.displayName
    }
}
```

For some reason **HeaderComp** is not exposed in latest version (28.2.1), that's why here we have to resolve it from **UserComponentRegistry**